# Is there a proper way to combine two beta prior distributions?

Tags: r, bayesian, empirical-bayes

I'm working on a research project which involves the assessment of NHL goalie performance (save percentage) using empirical Bayes. I found that the goalie distribution for career games played was peculiar. Nearly 50% of goalies play less than 10 games, whereas the others play on average 500 games. I *could* fit just one prior to this, however, I feel I'm giving too much weight to the goalies who barely play.

Could I instead fit two priors, one for goalies playing less than 10 games, another for goalies playing more than 10, and then use a simple model to determine the probability of a goalie belonging to each prior *based on their career thus far?* I would then just multiply both posteriors by the corresponding predicted group probability.

Comment: I presume by 'combining' you mean a [mixture of Beta priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/114959).

Comment: The difference is that the prior is not really bi-modal in my case, and the groupings are already made manually (goalie facing > 10 games or not).

Comment: @spazznolo the mixture distribution does not need to be bimodal. It will be bimodal if the two groups have very different distributions.

Comment: You could in theory have a higher level prior saying that a new goalie will go on to have a short or a long career.  You could even base this on how many games they have played (the more so far, the more likely they are eventually to exceed 10).  But this will end up being very complicated  and may not help your model

Comment: Right now my high level prior is a simple logistic regression which uses save percentage and number of shots faced to assign a probability to each prior. This way, as a goalie faces each shot, his class probability changes. Am I over-simplifying?